# IOS Multi-Image Solution

Tags: objective-c, ios

First of all, let me apologize for the title. Its a terrible one, but it was the only one I could think off...

So, my problem... I have multiple images with I would like to display one-by-one to a user... Like an intro or getting started guide.

I've been trying to figure out the best way to do it....
1) PageView with an image on each page
2) Put all the images into a PDF and embed the PDF in a scroll view

I don't care if they have to scroll vertically or horizontally.

Problem is, I'm not sure how to do either... And, which one would be better?... And, is there an alternate, better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't have thought that the embedded PDF is the graceful interface you want. PageView might be nice. If you want to do that, Apple's documentation on [PageViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html) is the place to start. Or something as simple as a bunch of ImageViews, of which all but the first is hidden, and then have a "next" button or something like that which animates the hiding of the current image and shows of the next image with some nice animated transition. See [Animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html).

As an aside, I don't know what your intro/getting started guide is for, but if it's for user interface design, I think a nice presentation is to create a black view that covers the whole view with 80-90% alpha, and then white text that shows the "tips" for using that screen. Or look at the iOS iPhoto and see how they handle tips, which is even a slicker way of doing it.

Finally, I'd suggest that if you need online instructions or the like, it might be a sign that your UI is too complicated or unintuitive (with my apologies in advance if I'm guessing incorrectly as to why you need online help in your app). Look at Apple's own iOS apps, which do amazing things, and they generally eschew online help and the like. I have to confess that I written online help screens, only to later reengineer the UI so it wasn't needed at all. The app should be "discoverable" and obvious.

Comment: +1 for the third paragraph.  If a screen in your app does something unusual, popping up a single tutorial image on the first visit to that screen is good.  More than that means you have a UI design problem.  If you're implementing 'reference' documentation for your app it should be fully scrollable, not a set of screens to page through.  A common choice there is to use UIWebView to display some local HTML files, although PDF would also work.

Comment: I agree that UIWebView is a very logical solution, too. I hadn't thought of that, which is funny because I actually use UIWebView for displaying lengthy legal copy, such as the customer's "Terms of Use". Incredibly simple way to display long body of text.

Comment: The application itself is easy to use; it consists of a single textfield and a button. The "guide" is an explanation of the importance of the app and why it was made... Either way, thanks. I'll look into the PageViews.

Answer (score 0):

Put each of your images in its own UIView inside of your XIB file.  You'll need to put all of those UIViews inside of a UIScrollview.

Inside your .M file have this function:

```
-(void)scrollToPage:(int)index
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(index * self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
}
```

When they click next call scroll to page with the proper page number.  This scrolls horizontally.

You'll also want to set the content size in the ViewDidLoad:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 4, self.view.frame.size.height);
```